# Linking Error: undefined reference to `MPI_Init' on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, linker, environment-variables, mpi

I am using OpenMPI library to write a program to run on Windows 7. I compile and build with C Free 4.0, Mingw.

Compiling is Ok but when the compiler links object, errors "undefined reference to ..." occurs.

I have set the environment already: I added OpenMPI lib, include and bin folder into C Free Build Directories. I added them into Windows environment variables too.

But the error still occurs.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: MPI libraires usually come with compiler wrappers like `mpicc`, `mpic++`, etc. that one normally uses to compile and link MPI program. If you cannot use the `mpicc` provided by Open MPI, then at least run `mpicc -showme:compile` and `mpicc -showme:link` to see what options `mpicc` provides to the compiler for the compile and link phases and adjust your project settings accordingly.

Comment: First time I've heard of the C-Free IDE.  Interestingly enough, it's not free.